Salesforce Web To Lead form captcha not being validated
We added reCaptcha to our web to lead form, we followed the steps in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=service.customizesupport_web_to_case_enable_recaptcha.htm&type=5
But the form can be submitted without ticking the captcha. I inspected the code and this is what is relevant:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
 function timestamp() { var response = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response"); if (response == null || response.value.trim() == "") {var elems = JSON.parse(document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value);elems["ts"] = JSON.stringify(new Date().getTime());document.getElementsByName("captcha_settings")[0].value = JSON.stringify(elems); } } setInterval(timestamp, 500);
</script>

<input type=hidden name='captcha_settings' value='{"keyname":"##","fallback":"true","orgId":"##","ts":""}'>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function recaptcha_callback(){
      alert("callback working");
      $('.button').prop("disabled", false);
   }
</script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="####" data-callback="recaptcha_callback"></div><br>
<input type="submit" name="Enviar">

What I notice is the callback for the captcha is alerting and a jquery command is trying to enable an element of class button. That is incorrect as the input has no defined class "button" and it is not disabled by default.
So I have two questions about this:

Does salesforce make the server-side validation with google of the token response?
I don't know what to change in the callback, as we do not want to make the input disabled, we just want to make the captcha required and validate it correctly, forcing the user to tick the checkbox when submitting the form. What is the best practice for this?

I'm kind of confused about all of this so if anyone can guide me with steps I would be appreciated
EDIT: For context, I already looked at many articles regarding this, and I found many solutions that involve making a client-side validation (like the incomplete auto-generated code from sf), but many comments of people noting that a server-side validation with google is required to make the captcha 100% secure.. this is why I'm asking this, as the salesforce documentation is not very clear about this.
